# Odoo - Add a new stage in "crm.stage"

Tags: python, xml, odoo-9

I added a new custom stage "Factory" and added it in the sales team too. Is it possible to change the order of the stages displayed in the form view? Its now displayed as: New - Request - Factory - Quotation - Finish - More. How can I display like: New - Request - Quotation - Factory - Finish - More.

Comment: I am not sure But you can change the value of the sequence on the table crm_stage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

Go to Sales > Leads & Opportunities > Stages

Click on small "dot" near check box and drag above or below for order.

https://postimg.org/image/ivecjzzuh/